# WebView Crashing When scrolling in Windows phone 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to load the payment gateway using `WebView.NavigateToString(response)`-method.

The page loads fine but when I scroll, the country or Month or date of the Webview page(payment gateway page) for selecting card details. In debug mode it works fine but when we use it in release mode - or you can say that when it is not in debug mode - it will crash.

I use a HockeyApp Crash Analytics for report but it doesn't show me any bug.

Where should i look for a solution?

Best regards Anurag

Comment: For a start, if the html contains any javascript and if it has issues than you can reroute the error via window.external.notify and catch that in webview scrpt_notify event handler.